# G++ does not recognise "//" as a comment

Tags: c++, bash, debugging, g++, cygwin

I'm trying to compile the following [code](http://forums.devarticles.com/c-c-help-52/help-with-c-numerical-integration-178104.html) on cygwin (CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.28(0.271/5/3) i686):

```
// the integration routine
template <typename Method, typename F, typename Float>
 double integrate(F f, Float a, Float b, int steps, Method m)
{
  double s = 0;
  double h = (b-a)/steps;
  for (int i = 0; i < steps; ++i)
    s += m(f, a + h*i, h);
  return h*s;
}

// methods
class rectangular
{
public:
  enum position_type { left, middle, right };
  rectangular(position_type pos): position(pos) {}
  template<typename F, typename Float>
   double operator()(F f, Float x, Float h) const
  {
    switch(position)
    {
    case left:
      return f(x);
    case middle:
      return f(x+h/2);
    case right:
      return f(x+h);
    }
  }
private:
  const position_type position;
};

class trapezium
{
public:
  template<typename F, typename Float>
   double operator()(F f, Float x, Float h) const
  {
    return (f(x) + f(x+h))/2;
  }
};

class simpson
{
public:
  template<typename F, typename Float>
   double operator()(F f, Float x, Float h) const
  {
    return (f(x) + 4*f(x+h/2) + f(x+h))/6;
  }
};


double f(double x) { return x*x; }

int main() {
    // sample usage

    // inside a function somewhere:
    double rl = integrate(f, 0.0, 1.0, 10, rectangular(rectangular::left));
    double rm = integrate(f, 0.0, 1.0, 10, rectangular(rectangular::middle));
    double rr = integrate(f, 0.0, 1.0, 10, rectangular(rectangular::right));
    double t  = integrate(f, 0.0, 1.0, 10, trapezium());
    double s  = integrate(f, 0.0, 1.0, 10, simpson());
}
```

but am receiving the following:

```
sh-4.1$ g++ -o "trapezoid_numerical_p3" trapezoid_numerical_p3.cpp 
sh-4.1$ ./trapezoid_numerical_p3.cpp 
./trapezoid_numerical_p3.cpp: line 1: //: is a directory
./trapezoid_numerical_p3.cpp: line 2: typename: No such file or directory
./trapezoid_numerical_p3.cpp: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'/trapezoid_numerical_p3.cpp: line 3: ` double integrate(F f, Float a, Float b, int steps, Method m)
sh-4.1$
```

The **`//: is a directory`** error seems to come from bash, and does not seem relevant to the c++ code.
[Googling for it](http://bit.ly/1lyw33c) didn't seem to produce any relevant leads.

**Can you suggest how to solve the above?**

Comment: You don't __execute__ a `.cpp` file.  You execute the __binary__ produced by the compiler.

Comment: you're trying to run your C++ file as a bash script, not the program that G++ just compiled

Comment: `g++ -o "trapezoid_numerical_p3" trapezoid_numerical_p3.cpp` <- can you do simply `g++ -o trapezoid_numerical_p3 trapezoid_numerical_p3.cpp && ./trapezoid_numerical_p3.exe ` ?

Comment: Even google gets confused when you make such errors.

Comment: @Mgetz I have my doubts about modern C++, but it's certainly possible to write a program which is acceptable to both the Bourne shell and early C (and Fortran): see http://www.ioccc.org/1986/applin.c.

Comment: @JamesKanze I bow before that insanity.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to run your `.cpp` file.

The command to run your program is (on Cygwin/Windows):

```
sh-4.1$ ./trapezoid_numerical_p3.exe
```

or (on Linux/Unix):

```
sh-4.1$ ./trapezoid_numerical_p3
```

Do not use the `.cpp` extension when you try to run your program.

Your comment the 'error seems to come from bash is correct', when you attempt to run the `.cpp` file, `bash` attempts to run it as a script and `bash` doesn't understand C (as noted by several comments).

Comment: the extension probably defaults to `.exe` since he's in cygwin environment

Comment: Good point @nurettin, added to the answer to cover both Cygwin and Linux.